# Slow stored procedure - SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

So i have created a stored procedure to use within my VB.NET program. This checks if several tables exist and then creates the relevant tables and inserts data into them using other tables within the database. Originally my stored procedure was running quite well, but i have recently made some changes to it, and now it takes over 5 minutes to run, which is causing problems within the program i have made as the time delay causes it to freeze. Therefore i need to cut down the time it takes to execute the stored procedure. Below i have identified the two parts of the stored procedure that are taking a long time. These are:

**Customers1 table**

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customers1') 
drop table Customers1

Create Table Customers1
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [AccountNumber] NVARCHAR(20),
 [AddressNo] int,
 [Name] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Address] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Address2] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Town] NVARCHAR(50), 
 [County] nvarchar(20),
 [Postcode] nvarchar(15),
 [Country] nvarchar(20),
 [Contact] nvarchar(81),
 [Phone] nvarchar(30),
 [FaxNo] NVARCHAR(30),
 [CurrentBalance] MONEY,
 [CreditLimit] MONEY,
 [Rep] NVARCHAR (50),
 [EmailAddress] NVARCHAR(225),
 [shiptoid] int default(0))

insert into Customers1([AccountNumber], [AddressNo],[Name],[Address],[Address2],[Town],[County],[Postcode],[Country],[Contact],[Phone],[FaxNo],[CurrentBalance],[CreditLimit],[Rep],[EmailAddress],[shiptoid])
select
[AccountNumber]
,0 as AddressNo
,[Company]
,[Address]
,[Address2]
,[city]
,[State]
,[ZIP]
,[Country]
,[FirstName]+ ' ' +[lastname]
,[PhoneNumber]
,[FaxNumber]
,[AccountBalance]
,[CreditLimit]
,case when customtext2 = '' then 'HOUSE' else customtext2 end AS Rep
,EmailAddress
,0
from customer

union all

select
[AccountNumber]
,0 as AddressNo
,shipto.[Company]
,shipto.[Address]
,shipto.[Address2]
,shipto.[city]
,shipto.[State]
,shipto.[ZIP]
,shipto.[Country]
,customer.[FirstName]+ ' ' +customer.[lastname]
,shipto.[PhoneNumber]
,shipto.[FaxNumber]
,customer.[AccountBalance]
,customer.[CreditLimit]
,case when customtext2 = '' then 'HOUSE' else customtext2 end AS Rep
,customer.EmailAddress
,shipto.id
from customer left join shipto
on customer.id= shipto.customerid
where shipto.company is not null
order by customer.accountnumber

declare @tableid int
declare @lasttableid int
declare @AccountNumber nvarchar(25)
declare @LineNumber int

set @tableID = 1
set @lasttableID = (select max([id]) from Customers1)
set @LineNumber = 1
set @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from customers1 where id = @tableid)

while @tableID <= @lasttableid
begin
    while @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from Customers1 where id = @tableid)  
        begin
            update Customers1
            set [AddressNo] = @LineNumber
            where [id] = @tableid
            set @LineNumber = @LineNumber + 1
            set @tableid = @tableid + 1
        end
    set @LineNumber = 1
    set @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from customers1 where id = @tableid)
end
```

**Orderlinehistory1 table**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'OrderLineHistory1') 
drop table OrderLineHistory1    

Create Table OrderLineHistory1
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [OrderNumber] nvarchar(25),
 [LineNo] INT,
 [ProductCode] nvarchar(25),
 [DueDate] DATETIME,
 [GrossSellingPrice] money,
 [OrderedQty] float,
 [DeliveredQty] float)

insert into OrderLineHistory1([OrderNumber],[LineNo],[ProductCode],[DueDate],[GrossSellingPrice],[OrderedQty],[DeliveredQty])
--select 
--purchaseorder.ponumber
--,0 as [LineNo]
--,item.itemlookupcode
--,Purchaseorder.RequiredDate
--,item.price
--,purchaseorderentry.quantityordered
--,purchaseorderentry.quantityreceivedtodate

--from PurchaseOrder,PurchaseOrderEntry,item
--where PurchaseOrder.id = PurchaseOrderEntry.PurchaseOrderID
--and purchaseorderentry.itemid = item.id
--and purchaseorder.potype = 0
--order by purchaseorder.ponumber,purchaseorderentry.id

select 
[orderentry].orderID
,0 as [LineNo]
,item.itemlookupcode
,[order].expirationorduedate
,orderentry.price
,orderentry.quantityonorder + orderentry.quantityRTD
,orderentry.quantityRTD
from orderentry left join [order] on orderentry.orderid = [order].ID
                left join item on orderentry.itemid = item.id
where orderentry.orderid >= (select min([ordernumber]) from pastorders)
order by [orderentry].orderID, [orderentry].ID                


declare @tableid1 int
declare @lasttableid1 int
declare @OrderNumber1 nvarchar(25)
declare @LineNumber1 int

set @tableID1 = 1
set @lasttableID1 = (select max([id]) from OrderLineHistory1)
set @LineNumber1 = 1
set @OrderNumber1 = (select OrderNumber from OrderLineHistory1 where id = @tableid1)

while @tableID1 <= @lasttableid1
begin
    while @OrderNumber1 = (select OrderNumber from OrderLineHistory1 where id = @tableid1)  
        begin
            update OrderLineHistory1
            set [LineNo] = @LineNumber1
            where [id] = @tableid1
            set @LineNumber1 = @LineNumber1 + 1
            set @tableid1 = @tableid1 + 1
        end
    set @LineNumber1 = 1
    set @OrderNumber1 = (select OrderNumber from OrderLineHistory1 where id = @tableid1)
end
```

Can anybody think of a more efficient way of writing these? Thank you

The whole stored procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure sp_retreatHomes
AS
--SET NOCOUNT ON

IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FamilyCode') 
drop table FamilyCode

Create Table FamilyCode
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [Code] nvarchar(17),
 [Name] nvarchar(30))

insert into FamilyCode([code],[name])
values ('Code','Name')

insert into FamilyCode([code],[name])

select Code,[name]
from category

union
select Code,[name]
from department
order by [name] 

IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customers1') 
drop table Customers1

Create Table Customers1
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [AccountNumber] NVARCHAR(20),
 [AddressNo] int,
 [Name] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Address] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Address2] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Town] NVARCHAR(50), 
 [County] nvarchar(20),
 [Postcode] nvarchar(15),
 [Country] nvarchar(20),
 [Contact] nvarchar(81),
 [Phone] nvarchar(30),
 [FaxNo] NVARCHAR(30),
 [CurrentBalance] MONEY,
 [CreditLimit] MONEY,
 [Rep] NVARCHAR (50),
 [EmailAddress] NVARCHAR(225),
 [shiptoid] int default(0))

insert into Customers1([AccountNumber], [AddressNo],[Name],[Address],[Address2],[Town],[County],[Postcode],[Country],[Contact],[Phone],[FaxNo],[CurrentBalance],[CreditLimit],[Rep],[EmailAddress],[shiptoid])
select
[AccountNumber]
,0 as AddressNo
,[Company]
,[Address]
,[Address2]
,[city]
,[State]
,[ZIP]
,[Country]
,[FirstName]+ ' ' +[lastname]
,[PhoneNumber]
,[FaxNumber]
,[AccountBalance]
,[CreditLimit]
,case when customtext2 = '' then 'HOUSE' else customtext2 end AS Rep
,EmailAddress
,0
from customer

union all

select
[AccountNumber]
,0 as AddressNo
,shipto.[Company]
,shipto.[Address]
,shipto.[Address2]
,shipto.[city]
,shipto.[State]
,shipto.[ZIP]
,shipto.[Country]
,customer.[FirstName]+ ' ' +customer.[lastname]
,shipto.[PhoneNumber]
,shipto.[FaxNumber]
,customer.[AccountBalance]
,customer.[CreditLimit]
,case when customtext2 = '' then 'HOUSE' else customtext2 end AS Rep
,customer.EmailAddress
,shipto.id
from customer left join shipto
on customer.id= shipto.customerid
where shipto.company is not null
order by customer.accountnumber

declare @tableid int
declare @lasttableid int
declare @AccountNumber nvarchar(25)
declare @LineNumber int

set @tableID = 1
set @lasttableID = (select max([id]) from Customers1)
set @LineNumber = 1
set @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from customers1 where id = @tableid)

while @tableID <= @lasttableid
begin
    while @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from Customers1 where id = @tableid)  
        begin
            update Customers1
            set [AddressNo] = @LineNumber
            where [id] = @tableid
            set @LineNumber = @LineNumber + 1
            set @tableid = @tableid + 1
        end
    set @LineNumber = 1
    set @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from customers1 where id = @tableid)
end



IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CatalogueProducts1') 
drop table CatalogueProducts1

Create Table CatalogueProducts1 
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [CatalogueCode] nvarchar(25),
 [ProductCode] nvarchar(25),
 [DisplaySequence] int)

insert into CatalogueProducts1([CatalogueCode],[ProductCode], [DisplaySequence])

SELECT case when left(SubDescription1,4) = '' then 'NA' else left(SubDescription1,4) end
,[ItemLookupCode]
,0
from dbo.Item
Order by left(SubDescription1,4) asc

declare @tableid2 int
declare @lasttableid2 int
declare @CatalogueCode nvarchar(25)
declare @DisplaySequence int

set @tableID2 = 1
set @lasttableID2 = (select max([id]) from CatalogueProducts1)
set @DisplaySequence = 1
set @CatalogueCode = (select CatalogueCode from CatalogueProducts1 where id = @tableid2)

while @tableID2 <= @lasttableid2
begin
    while @CatalogueCode = (select CatalogueCode from CatalogueProducts1 where id = @tableid2)  
        begin
            update CatalogueProducts1
            set [DisplaySequence] = @DisplaySequence
            where [id] = @tableid2
            set @DisplaySequence = @DisplaySequence + 1
            set @tableid2 = @tableid2 + 1
        end
    set @DisplaySequence = 1
    set @CatalogueCode = (select CatalogueCode from CatalogueProducts1 where id = @tableid2)
end

IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CatalogueProducts') 
drop table CatalogueProducts

Create Table CatalogueProducts 
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [CatalogueCode] nvarchar(25),
 [ProductCode] nvarchar(25),
 [DisplaySequence] nvarchar(25))

insert into CatalogueProducts([CatalogueCode],[ProductCode], [DisplaySequence])  
values('CatalogueCode','ProductCode', 'DisplaySequence')

insert into CatalogueProducts([CatalogueCode],[ProductCode], [DisplaySequence])  
select CatalogueCode,ProductCode,convert(nvarchar,DisplaySequence)
from CatalogueProducts1
order by id


IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PastOrders') 
drop table PastOrders

Create Table PastOrders
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [OrderNumber] NVARCHAR(25),
 [AccountCode] nvarchar(20),
 [AddressNo] nvarchar(10),
 [OrderDate] NVARCHAR(50),
 [DueDate] NVARCHAR(50),
 [RepCode] NVARCHAR(50))
insert into PastOrders([OrderNumber],[AccountCode],[AddressNo],[OrderDate],[DueDate],[RepCode]) 
values ('OrderNumber','AccountCode','AddressNo','OrderDate','DueDate','RepCode')

insert into PastOrders([OrderNumber],[AccountCode],[AddressNo],[OrderDate],[DueDate],[RepCode])

SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Order].ID) AS OrderNumber
,Customer.AccountNumber
,case when shiptoid = 0 then 1 else shiptoid end AS AddressNo
,isnull(convert(nvarchar,(datepart(dd,[order].ExpirationOrDueDate))) 
+ '/' + convert(nvarchar,(datepart(mm,[order].ExpirationOrDueDate)))
+ '/' + convert(nvarchar,(datepart(yy,[order].ExpirationOrDueDate))),'')
,isnull(convert(nvarchar,(datepart(dd,[order].LastUpdated))) 
+ '/' + convert(nvarchar,(datepart(mm,[order].LastUpdated)))
+ '/' + convert(nvarchar,(datepart(yy,[order].LastUpdated))),'')
,case when customer.customtext2 = '' then 'HOUSE' else customer.customtext2 end
FROM [Order]
LEFT JOIN Customer ON [order].customerID = customer.ID
where Customer.AccountNumber is not null
and [order].[time] > (select getdate() - 550)



update PastOrders
set [AddressNo] = convert(nvarchar,customers1.addressno)
from PastOrders,customers1
where PastOrders.[AddressNo] = customers1.shiptoid
and PastOrders.[AddressNo] <> 'AddressNo' 

update PastOrders
set [AddressNo] = 1
where [AddressNo] not in (select id from shipto)
and PastOrders.[AddressNo] <> 'AddressNo' 







--fix customers
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Customers') 
drop table Customers

Create Table Customers
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [AccountNumber] NVARCHAR(20),
 [AddressNo] nvarchar(30),
 [Name] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Address] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Address2] NVARCHAR(50),
 [Town] NVARCHAR(50), 
 [County] nvarchar(20),
 [Postcode] nvarchar(15),
 [Country] nvarchar(20),
 [Contact] nvarchar(81),
 [Phone] nvarchar(30),
 [FaxNo] NVARCHAR(30),
 [CurrentBalance] NVARCHAR(225),
 [CreditLimit] NVARCHAR(225),
 [Rep] NVARCHAR (255),
 [EmailAddress] NVARCHAR(225))

insert into Customers([AccountNumber], [AddressNo],[Name],[Address],[Address2],[Town],[County],[Postcode],[Country],[Contact],[Phone],[FaxNo],[CurrentBalance],[CreditLimit],[Rep],[EmailAddress])
values ('AccountNumber', 'AddressNo','Name','Address','Address2','Town','County','Postcode','Country','Contact','Phone','FaxNo','CurrentBalance','CreditLimit','Rep','EmailAddress')


insert into Customers([AccountNumber], [AddressNo],[Name],[Address],[Address2],[Town],[County],[Postcode],[Country],[Contact],[Phone],[FaxNo],[CurrentBalance],[CreditLimit],[Rep],[EmailAddress])
select [AccountNumber],
convert(nvarchar,[AddressNo])
,[Name]
,[Address]
,[Address2]
,[Town]
,[County]
,[Postcode]
,[Country]
,[Contact]
,[Phone]
,[FaxNo]
,convert(nvarchar,[CurrentBalance])
,convert(nvarchar,[CreditLimit])
,[Rep]
,[EmailAddress]
from customers1
order by [id] asc


IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Products') 
drop table Products

Create Table Products
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [ProductCode] NVARCHAR(25),
 [Description] NVARCHAR(30),
 [UOM] NVARCHAR(4),
 [Carton] NVARCHAR(30),
 [StdPrice] NVARCHAR(25),
  [SalesPrice] NVARCHAR(25),
 [StockQty] NVARCHAR(25),
 [PODueIn] NVARCHAR(25),
 [OnSOQty] NVARCHAR(25),
 [DueDate] NVARCHAR(25),
 [Barcode] NVARCHAR(25),
 [FamilyCode1] NVARCHAR(30),
 [FamilyCode2] NVARCHAR(30))


 insert into Products([ProductCode]
,[Description]
,[UOM]
,[Carton]
,[StdPrice]
,[SalesPrice]
,[StockQty]
,[PODueIn]
,[OnSOQty]
,[DueDate]
,[Barcode]
,[FamilyCode1]
,[FamilyCode2])

Values('ProductCode','Description','UOM','Carton','StdPrice','SalesPrice','StockQty','PODueIn','OnSOQty','DueDate','Barcode','FamilyCode1','FamilyCode2') 

insert into Products([ProductCode]
,[Description]
,[UOM]
,[Carton]
,[Barcode]
,[StdPrice]
,[StockQty]
,[PODueIn]
,[OnSOQty]
,[DueDate]
,[FamilyCode1]
,[FamilyCode2]
,[SalesPrice])

select [ItemLookupCode]
,[Description]
,CASE [UnitOfMeasure] WHEN '' THEN 'EACH' ELSE UnitOfMeasure END AS UOM
,[SubDescription3]
, [Alias]
, convert(nvarchar,item.[Price])
, convert(nvarchar,item.[quantity])
, isnull(View_PO.PODueIn,0) as PODueIN
, convert(nvarchar,item.[QuantityCommitted])
, isnull(convert(nvarchar,(datepart(dd,View_PO.DueDate))) 
+ '/' + convert(nvarchar,(datepart(mm,View_PO.DueDate)))
+ '/' + convert(nvarchar,(datepart(yy,View_PO.DueDate))),'') as DueDate
, isnull(department.[name],'') as Department
, isnull(category.[name],'') as Category
, convert(nvarchar,item.[SalePrice])
from Item 
LEFT JOIN Alias ON alias.ItemID = Item.id
left join View_PO on item.id = View_PO.itemid
inner join firstAlias on alias.ID=firstAlias.id and firstAlias.ItemID=item.id
left join department on item.departmentid = department.id
left join category on item.categoryid = category.id
WHERE SubDescription3 NOT IN ('0','')
order by item.id asc



IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'OrderLineHistory1') 
drop table OrderLineHistory1    

Create Table OrderLineHistory1
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [OrderNumber] nvarchar(25),
 [LineNo] INT,
 [ProductCode] nvarchar(25),
 [DueDate] DATETIME,
 [GrossSellingPrice] money,
 [OrderedQty] float,
 [DeliveredQty] float)

insert into OrderLineHistory1([OrderNumber],[LineNo],[ProductCode],[DueDate],[GrossSellingPrice],[OrderedQty],[DeliveredQty])
--select 
--purchaseorder.ponumber
--,0 as [LineNo]
--,item.itemlookupcode
--,Purchaseorder.RequiredDate
--,item.price
--,purchaseorderentry.quantityordered
--,purchaseorderentry.quantityreceivedtodate

--from PurchaseOrder,PurchaseOrderEntry,item
--where PurchaseOrder.id = PurchaseOrderEntry.PurchaseOrderID
--and purchaseorderentry.itemid = item.id
--and purchaseorder.potype = 0
--order by purchaseorder.ponumber,purchaseorderentry.id

select 
[orderentry].orderID
,0 as [LineNo]
,item.itemlookupcode
,[order].expirationorduedate
,orderentry.price
,orderentry.quantityonorder + orderentry.quantityRTD
,orderentry.quantityRTD
from orderentry left join [order] on orderentry.orderid = [order].ID
                left join item on orderentry.itemid = item.id
where orderentry.orderid >= (select min([ordernumber]) from pastorders)
order by [orderentry].orderID, [orderentry].ID                


declare @tableid1 int
declare @lasttableid1 int
declare @OrderNumber1 nvarchar(25)
declare @LineNumber1 int

set @tableID1 = 1
set @lasttableID1 = (select max([id]) from OrderLineHistory1)
set @LineNumber1 = 1
set @OrderNumber1 = (select OrderNumber from OrderLineHistory1 where id = @tableid1)

while @tableID1 <= @lasttableid1
begin
    while @OrderNumber1 = (select OrderNumber from OrderLineHistory1 where id = @tableid1)  
        begin
            update OrderLineHistory1
            set [LineNo] = @LineNumber1
            where [id] = @tableid1
            set @LineNumber1 = @LineNumber1 + 1
            set @tableid1 = @tableid1 + 1
        end
    set @LineNumber1 = 1
    set @OrderNumber1 = (select OrderNumber from OrderLineHistory1 where id = @tableid1)
end


IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'OrderLineHistory') 
drop table OrderLineHistory 

Create Table OrderLineHistory
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [OrderNumber] nvarchar(25),
 [LineNo] nvarchar(25),
 [ProductCode] nvarchar(25),
 [DueDate] nvarchar(25),
 [GrossSellingPrice]nvarchar(25),
 [OrderedQty] nvarchar(25),
 [DeliveredQty] nvarchar(25))

insert into OrderLineHistory([OrderNumber],[LineNo],[ProductCode],[DueDate],[GrossSellingPrice],[OrderedQty],[DeliveredQty])
values('OrderNumber','LineNo','ProductCode','DueDate','GrossSellingPrice','OrderedQty','DeliveredQty')  

insert into OrderLineHistory([OrderNumber],[LineNo],[ProductCode],[DueDate],[GrossSellingPrice],[OrderedQty],[DeliveredQty])
select [OrderNumber],convert(varchar(25),[LineNo]),[ProductCode]
,isnull(convert(nvarchar,(datepart(dd,DueDate))) 
+ '/' + convert(nvarchar,(datepart(mm,DueDate)))
+ '/' + convert(nvarchar,(datepart(yy,DueDate))),'')
,[GrossSellingPrice],[OrderedQty],[DeliveredQty]
from OrderLineHistory1
order by id asc 

-- Reps
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Reps') 
drop table Reps

Create Table Reps
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [Code] nvarchar(17),
 [Name] nvarchar(30))

insert into Reps([code],[Name])
values ('Code','Name')

insert into Reps([code],[Name])
select distinct customtext2,customtext2
from customer
where customtext2 <> ''
order by customtext2

--Catalogues
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Catalogues') 
drop table Catalogues

Create Table Catalogues
(ID int identity(1,1),
 [Code] nvarchar(17),
 [Description] nvarchar(30))

insert into Catalogues([code],[Description])
values ('Code','Description')

insert into Catalogues([code],[Description])
select  distinct left(subdescription1,4),subdescription1  
from item
where subdescription1 <> ''

union

select 'NA', 'Not Assigned'
order by subdescription1



-- select * from reps
-- select * from Catalogues
-- select * from FamilyCode
-- select * from CatalogueProducts
-- select * from customers
-- select * from products
-- select * from pastorders
-- select * from orderlinehistory
```

Comment: Just to let people know he OrderLineHistory1 table is causing the main problem, with it taking around 5 minutes to run, the customers1 table takes about 30 seconds but i could still do with this being more efficient

Comment: what change did you make that made your SP start to run slowly?

Comment: Are your tables: orderentry, order, pastorders indexed on the columns you are joining on?

Comment: @I.K. i changed it so it included the while loop, i think because there is so many records within the database this is why it is taking so long. Maybe there is a way i could write the SQL so the while loop is more efficient, or a way i could write something that does the same thing as the while loop but is quicker?

Comment: AH! Of course, looping on a big table will kill your performance. Best to re-write using set-based queries if you can. What are you trying to achieve with the while loop, maybe I can help.

Comment: Yeah thats what i thought :) can you think of a better way of writing it? I'm fairly new to SQL server so i know the basics but i just need a bit of guidance with it really :)

Comment: Do you want to edit my post so it includes the whole procedure? it might be easier for you to read and understand that way

Comment: That would be good, please edit your post and I will have a look. Also tell me what you want to achieve with the while loop.

Comment: Okay i have edited the post, and i think the while loop is used to update a variable called line number so only certain values are selected. Unfortunately a colleague wrote this part of my SQL and he is away, but from my understanding that is what the loop was used for. Thank you

Comment: OK. There are two immediate things you can try. Performance tuning is a trial and error process really. First thing, I noticed that for the tables you create e.g customer 1, there are no indexes on these tables, yet they are used in the loop. Try creating an index on the tables you create. Secondly, try splitting out this BIG stored procedure into smaller stored procedures. Have one main SP which does the insert into the tables and then call another SP which does the logic; this way the optimiser will know the statistical distribution of the data in the tables and so can make some inferences.

Comment: I have to say though, you have DOUBLE while loops in there. That's going to kill BIG TIME, especially if you have a lot of data in these tables.

Comment: Is there any alternative to the while loops that i can try?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you can explain to me in English sentences what you are trying to do, maybe we can re-write it. But it is difficult to know you exact intention from just reading the queries and without any visible data.

Comment: Okay well the stored procedure is used to grab data from other tables within the database, and then produce tables to insert this data into. This is because within my program i select these new tables and send the data to CSV files. Meaning the store procedure is used to basically sort needed data into new tables so they can be selected easier. Is there any other info you need? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can re-write the looping logic just using one while loop. I can't say for sure as I don't know your exact business requirements and I can't test on any data. Try it and let me know:

```
set @tableID = 1
set @lasttableID = (select max([id]) from Customers1)
set @LineNumber = 1
set @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from customers1 where id = @tableid)

while @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber 
                        from Customers1 
                        where id = @tableid)  
begin
    update Customers1
    set [AddressNo] = @LineNumber
    where [id] = @tableid

    set @LineNumber = @LineNumber + 1
    set @tableid = @tableid + 1
    set @AccountNumber = (select AccountNumber from customers1 where id = @tableid)

    if (@tableId <= @lasttableid)
        BREAK
    else
        CONTINUE
end
```

Comment: Is that just for the customers 1 table? :) and thank you i appreciate the help :)

Comment: basically your while loops follow a similar pattern. apply the above in all cases and let me know if it speeds up the SP. Also try the other strategies I mentioned before. But try one at a time, try changing the looping queries to follow the pattern up, test it. If not ok, then add indexes as I mentioned before. If not ok, then split out the SPs. After that, then you may need to really approach the problem entirely differently.

Comment: Also once i replaced my previous code for Customers1 with the code above it ran slower for some reason :/ i think i could do with using a set based query rather than a while loop, i just don't know how i could write it

Comment: add an index to customers1 on the id column and let me know

Comment: However i have tried that method on my orderlinehistory1 table and it seems to have cut it down, let me just compare the data from before and now

Comment: The order line history table looks to be working okay so thank you very much! :) i will have a go at adding an index for customers1 and seeing what happens

Comment: Just modified the query to take out the breaking condition in while loop predicate. I'm thinking the optimiser is getting confused there.

Comment: I've just indexed it and everything it working fine, thanks for all the help really appreciate it :)

Comment: I've just been in contact with my colleague the second while loop was used to increase line no until the next order number was met then the line number would start counting from 1 again :/

Comment: If you analyse those loops carefully looking for what are the variants and invariants, you could clean them up and do with only one while loop. That leads to faster and easier to read and maintain code. I can't really help you here as I would need your business data to make sure no regression bugs are introduced.